# How do I write these equations in my doc?

Tags: equations

[image]

I don't know how to write LaTeX, can someone help me write this notation in latex format so I can complete my doc?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You need to read some introductory text about LaTeX, for example https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be basic task in LaTeX. What you try so far? Where you stuck? At how to write bold slant variables?

It seems that you you need to make yourself more familiar with it. Here on site is a lot of examples of how to write equation, also see some  introductory text about LaTeX, for example [No so short introduction to LaTeX](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), than [Wikibooks: Mathematics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics), etc.

For first equation may try to use `bm` package for math boldface variables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}


\begin{document}
\[
f(x) = \bm{x}^\top \bm{W}^{d\times C}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the showed way you try write the next equation yourself.