# How i write this equation

Tags: math-mode

[image: 1]

I don't know anything about how to write **Latex**, can someone help me? Write this equation.

Comment: The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/684886/106162) to [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/684883/106162) wasn't any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  f(\boldsymbol{x}) = 
    \boldsymbol{x}^\top
    \boldsymbol{W}^{d \times n}_{(h_1)}
    \boldsymbol{W}^{n \times C}_{(\text{out})}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I’d prefer `\bm`